# XSL-FO using empty tables cells and leaders

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm using table columns with leaders (dotted line) to create a visual connection between content in different cells. E.g:

```
Text in col one..........Text in col two
```

I use an "spacer" column to keep a space between text in different cells and the spacer column has a dotted leader.

My problem is that depending on the actual text in the first column there will be an empty space after the leader of column 1 and before column2, E.g

```
Text in col one.....  .....Text in col two
```

Sometimes there will be no space but other times the space will a few pixels.

Example code:

```
<fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" margin-left="0"
    margin-right="0" padding-before="0" padding-after="0"
    border-width="0" font-family="Franklin" font-size="12pt">
    <fo:table-column column-width="50mm" /> 
    <fo:table-column column-width="10mm" />
    <fo:table-column column-width="50mm" /> 
    <fo:table-body>

        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell display-align="after">
                <fo:block text-align-last="justify">
                    <xsl:text>Text in col1</xsl:text>   
                    <fo:leader leader-pattern="dots" />             
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>                                
            <fo:table-cell display-align="after">
                <fo:block text-align-last="justify">                                       
                    <fo:leader leader-pattern="dots" />             
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>                                
            <fo:table-cell display-align="after">
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:text>Text in col2</xsl:text>                                                       
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>                         
    </fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
```

Does anyone know how to get rid of that annoying space ?

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work.  Basically just removed the middle column and set the last column to full justify with a leader in front of the text.

```
<fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" margin-left="0" margin-right="0" padding-before="0" padding-after="0" border-width="0" font-family="Franklin" font-size="12pt"> 
    <fo:table-column column-width="50mm" /> 
    <fo:table-column column-width="50mm" /> 
    <fo:table-body> 
        <fo:table-row> 
            <fo:table-cell display-align="after"> 
                <fo:block text-align-last="justify">
                    <xsl:text>Text in col1</xsl:text> 
                    <fo:leader leader-pattern="dots" />
               </fo:block> 
            </fo:table-cell> 
            <fo:table-cell display-align="after"> 
                <fo:block text-align-last="justify"> 
                       <fo:leader leader-pattern="dots" />
                       <xsl:text>Text in col2</xsl:text> 
                </fo:block> 
            </fo:table-cell> 
        </fo:table-row> 
    </fo:table-body> 
</fo:table>
```